# Why is my character animation going out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, pygame

I'm trying to get a punch Animation working for my character. But when I run the game I press the key to punch and when it finishes the animation the game gets an error

> ```
> \Desktop\python projects\Ultamate Brawl\Ultamite BRAWL.py", line 41, in redrawGameWindow
>    win.blit(PunchR[punchcount//2], (xcor, ycor))
>        IndexError: list index out of range
> [Finished in 6.4s]
> ```

an I looked at my code and it looks fine

```
def redrawGameWindow():
    global punchcount 
    global walkcount

    win.blit(bg, (-70,0))
    if walkcount + 1 >= 27:
        walkcount = 0
    if punch == True:
        if punchcount > 49:
            punchcount = 1
        win.blit(PunchR[punchcount//2], (xcor, ycor))
        punchcount += 1
        
        
    elif isjump:
        win.blit(superjump, (xcor,ycor))
    
    elif left:
        if walkcount > 49:
            walkcount = 1
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkcount//4], (xcor, ycor))
        walkcount += 1

    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkcount//4], (xcor,ycor))
        walkcount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (xcor,ycor))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to evaluate the number of elements in the list `PunchR` by [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len). Set `punchcount=0` if the subscription would access out of bounds. So your algorithm is independent of the length of the list:

```py
if punchcount//2 >= len(PunchR):
    punchcount = 0
win.blit(PunchR[punchcount//2], (xcor, ycor))
punchcount += 1
```

If you want to run  the animation just once, you have to set `punch = False` when the end of the list is reached:

```
if punch == True:
    if punchcount//2 >= len(PunchR):
        punchcount = 0
        punch = False
    win.blit(PunchR[punchcount//2], (xcor, ycor))
    punchcount += 1
```

Comment: ok it solved the problem but it wont stop it does the full animation but never stops